# Change html value dynamically from url parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetPDF(string paramYear)
{
   list = new List<Exam>
   {
     new Exam(){Year= "2016"},
     new Exam(){Year= "2017"},
     new Exam(){Year= "2018"}
   };
  return View(list.Where(a => a.Year == paramYear));
}
```

That return the following view **GetPDF** view:

```
<body >
    <object  data="~/Content/Exams/2016/T205_16.pdf" type="text/html" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></object>   
</body>
```

I need the following: when the GetPDF method invoked I want that this part will replaced with the correct path `data="~/Content/Exams/2016/T205_16.pdf"`

For example, If GetPDF was invoked with "2018" the the path inside html will replaced to:
`data="~/Content/Exams/2016/exam_2018.pdf"`

How can I achive that? I tried to get the url paremer [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/9184610) but it didn't worked well

Comment: Pass it as a parameter in your ViewModel.

Comment: @SLaks Do you mean like `ViewBag` ? (I'm new with mvc)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3#using-a-model-to-pass-information-to-our-view

Comment: @SLaks It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the parameter from the controller to the view using a view model class.

For more details, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3#using-a-model-to-pass-information-to-our-view).